# Setting the Position of an MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I need to set the position of an `MFC Dialog` to some `relative position` (Upper Right Corner) to it's parent dialog. I am using the following code:

**MainFrame.h:**

```
/*Creation of Dialog*/
SearchCommands* searchDialog;
```

**MainFrame.cpp:**

```
/*In Constructor*/
searchDialog = new SearchCommands();

/*In an Init Method*/
if (!searchDialog->Create(IDD_COMMANDS_SEARCH, this))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create Search Dialog\n");
    delete searchDialog;
}

/*Button Click Event*/
void CMainFrame::OnSearchButton()
{
    /*Get the ordinates of parent*/
    RECT rect;
    CWnd::GetWindowRect(&rect);

   /*searchDialog is the pointer to a dynamically created Dialog*/
   searchDialog->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndNoTopMost,rect.left,rect.bottom,rect.left,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW );

   searchDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

But the Dialog disappears instead of being shown properly. I could not understand *how the parameters should be passed to [`CWnd::SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx) method* so may be I am doing something wrong there.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Show more code. Is this code in `OninitDialog` ? Also: try `MoveWindow`, which is simpler instead of `SetWindowPos`.

Comment: I am opening the dialog in a button click event so this is the code of `OnSearch` event in the parent window.

Comment: Please edit your question and show more code. Your `SetWindowPosition`or `MoveWindow` must be in `OnititDialog`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Kindly see the code now, this is what I was trying to do

Comment: OK, that's better. I'll have a look.

Comment: One more thing that was wrong anyway: `SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndNoTopMost,rect.left,rect.bottom,rect.left,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW );` should be `SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndNoTopMost,rect.left,rect.top,rect.right,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW );`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Kindly see my comment on your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CRect rect;
searchDialog->GetWindowRect(rect);
int dx = rect.Width();
int dy = rect.Height();
GetWindowRect(rect);
rect.left = rect.right - dx;
rect.bottom = rect.top + dy;
searchDialog->MoveWindow(rect);
searchDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

This will move your dialog the upper right position of your parent window.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me :) but I need to move the dialog to the top **right** corner. What should I modify?

Comment: @ItbanSaeed : My answer was actually wrong. I edited it and now it does what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works !!  I wish I could you give another upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass relative coordinates to `SetWindowPos` if the window is a child window. `GetWindowRect` returns you screen (absolute) coordinates. You cannot pass these to `SetWindowPos` for your scenario. Use `GetClientRect` on the parent and pass this rect to `SetWindowPos`.

```
RECT rect;
CWnd::GetClientRect(&rect);   // Only line changed
searchDialog->SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndNoTopMost,rect.left,rect.bottom,rect.left,rect.bottom,SWP_SHOWWINDOW );
```

Comment: @ItbanSaeed Only replace GetWindowRect by GetClientRect.